# Tinymce font-color not support after saving in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using tinymce text editor in codeigniter fusion invoice. after saving text the editor will show the content like below in textarea source code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p><span ff00ff="" ff99cc="">dffghfgh</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

My tinymce code is

```
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        verify_html: false,         
        plugins: [
            "fullpage",
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste",
            "textcolor"
        ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | fontselect fontsizeselect styleselect | bold italic | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
          textcolor_map: [
            "000000", "Black",.. ]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is [XSS filtering](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/security.html).

Please use this:

`$this->input->post('your_input_name', false)`

instead of this:

`$this->input->post('your_input_name')`